# Como ordenar um array de objetos usando TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Tenho o seguinte *array*:

```
public arr = [ 
    { id: 1, name: 'João das Neves'},
    { id: 2, name: 'Areia Stark'},
    { id: 3, name: 'Sonsa Stark'}    
];
```

Gostaria de ordenar esse *array* pela atributo `name`, ficando desta forma:

```
public arr = [ 
    { id: 2, name: 'Areia Stark'},
    { id: 1, name: 'João das Neves'},        
    { id: 3, name: 'Sonsa Stark'}    
];
```

Como ordenar um *array* de objetos usando TypeScript?

Comment: Gostei dos nomes no array :D

Comment: Por que "usando TypeScript"? Não seria a mesma coisa se usar JavaScript normalmente?

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar o **.sort()** para isso:

```
arr.sort((a, b) => (a.name < b.name) ? -1 : 1);
```